# Measurable cardinals and the fundamental theorem

Tags: mathematical-logic

Who was the first mathematician to define and investigate measurable cardinals?
And how long did it take for the fundamental theorem of measurable cardinals to be hypothesized and proven?

I would be very grateful for some background information on these questions.

Comment: According to this paper, it was Stansilaw Ulam who first defined measurable cardinals and investigated their properties in his 1930 paper Zur Maßtheorie in der allgemeinen Mengenlehre., Source : http://mathreview.uwaterloo.ca/archive/volii/2/measure-cardinality.pdf

Comment: What is the "fundamental theorem of measurable cardinals"? Is it Ulam's proof of their weak inaccessibility, Solovay's equiconsistency theorem, Keisler-Scott's critical point characterization, incompatibility with the axiom of constructibility, or something else?

Comment: I mean Keisler-Scott's critical point characterization, i. e. a cardinal is measurable iff it is the critical point of a non-trivial elementary embedding of the universe V into a transitive class M.

Comment: This paper on the Stanford site appears to contain exactly what you are looking for in a readable summary form :http://www-logic.stanford.edu/seminar/1516/Mieczyslaw_1103.pdf starting with Banach and Ulam's definition and leading to Keisler's theorem via Scott's results together with those of Łoś and Mostkowski. It even has a cool picture of Bullwinkle J. Moose! I would have summarised it for you here, but that might give the impression that I fully understood it!

Comment: @NickR Thanks a lot! I would love to have some dates, and especially some white sources, but that's already great! How did you found that?

Answer (score 2):

You can see : Dov Gabbay & Akihiro Kanamori & John Woods (editors), [Handbook of the History of Logic. Volume 6: Sets and Extensions in the Twentieth Century](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZF_QckMFy-oC&pg=PR5) (2012), especially :

- **Ch.1** : Set Theory from Cantor to Cohen, By A.Kanamori,
- **Ch.2** : History of the Continuum in the 20th Century, by J.Steprans,
- **Ch.4** : Large Cardinals with Fprcing, by A.Kanamori.

Also : Akihiro Kanamori, [The Higher Infinite : Large Cardinals in Set Theory from Their Beginnings](https://books.google.it/books?id=FH_n84ocuSMC&pg=PR9) (2nd ed., 2009) : **Introduction** and **Chapter 1. Beginnings**.

Maybe useful also : Matthew Foreman & Akihiro Kanamori (editors), [Handbook of Set Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=DLCyehuI0i0C&pg=PR11) (2010) : **Introduction** by A.Kanamori.

---

For historical context, you can see also : Gregory Moore, [Zermelo's Axiom of Choice : Its Origin Development and Influence](https://books.google.it/books?id=3RLGKcEjVIoC&pg=PA196) (1982): **Ch.4 The Warsaw School**.